# ecryptfs-mount-private ERROR

Tags: ecryptfs

> ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not set up properly

I forgot my password and a computer person set up a new profile on my linux machine with a new login password which I know.  The problem is I get this error when I type in the terminal: `ecryptfs-mount-private`.

I'm not sure this is related, but how do I set up my directory properly?

Comment: Is the encrypted directory empty (containing no important data, we can just remove it and make a new one) or do you need to recover the files from within it?

Comment: The encrypted directory has files in it.  I need to recover the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want these two eCryptFS tools (scripts really):

1. `ecryptfs-recover-private` - find and mount any encrypted private directories

   Use this to mount your old encrypted home, and copy / back them up somewhere safe.
2. `ecryptfs-migrate-home` - migrate a user's home to directory to an encrypted home setup

   It's `man` page contains this warning:

   ```
   WARNING: Make a complete backup copy of the  non-encrypted  data  to
   another  system  or  external media. This script is dangerous and in
   case of an error, could result in data lost, or lock USER out of the
   system!
   ```

So I'd definitely do the `ecryptfs-recover-private` and create backup copies first, if the data has any value.

**BUT** you absolutely must have your **old login passphrase** in order to decrypt your old encrypted home (unless you already have a backup copy of the actual eCryptfs **mount passphrase**). From your statement *I forgot my password* you might be out of luck unless you can guess/remember your old password.

Recovering your files from a backup copy would be much easier, if you have a backup copy (everyone really *should* have backup copies of important data, all drives fail eventually, and forgetting passphrases is easy to do).

FYI, your actual encrypted files and `wrapped-passphrase` file should be stored in `/home/.ecryptfs`, along with every user's encrypted home. The actual home folder (for example `/home/[username]` only has links to the actual folders, and 2 help files. Specifically:

- Your encrypted files should be in `/home/.ecryptfs/[username]/.Private`
- `wrapped-passphrase` and other config files should be in `/home/.ecryptfs/[username]/.ecryptfs`